# I am having trouble understanding this lambda calculus from Understanding Computation

Tags: ruby, lambda

In Tom Stuart's book Understanding Computation, there is a chapter devoted to rebuilding FizzBuzz through Procs/Lambdas. He begins by talking about how to define numbers through procs, and shows that a 'number' could be represented by a proc that is run `x` number of times for the number it represents (i.e., 1 is proc[x], 2 is proc[proc[x]], etc). That makes sense. However, the next bit he defines a `to_integer` method as such:

```
def to_integer(proc)
  proc[-> n { n + 1 }][0]
end
```

This has broken my brain. I cannot make sense of what this means. I have admittedly not worked with procs much, other than lambdas in scope while working with rails.

I can simplify it to

```
def to_integer(proc)
  proc[Proc.new(n){ n + 1 }][0]
end
```

...but that is as far as I can seem to get. Can anyone explain or simplify this in a way that is easier to understand? What is going on here? I'm confused by the proc[`x`][0] style, where `n` is coming from. I am just having a very tough time understanding this.

In the book, the procs being passed to this method are like so:

```
ZERO = -> p { -> x { x } }
ONE  = -> p { -> x { p[x] } }
TWO  = -> p { -> x { p[p[x]] } }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in to_integer chains 2 proc calls using Ruby's [] shorthand for calling a proc.

It's helpful to walk through it by hand in IRB. Lets start by defining ZERO(a lambda):

```
ZERO = -> p { -> x { x } }
=> #<Proc:0x007ff86a147930@(irb):103 (lambda)>
```

You will see different numbers here but the important part is that ZERO is a lambda, which is a proc.

Let's give the anonymous lambda in to_integer a name to make it clear what's going on there. Using the "stabby lambda" syntax:

```
INCR = -> n { n + 1 }
INCR[2]
=> 3 
INCR[3]
=> 4
```

We send in a number, it returns that number plus 1.

We then pass ZERO into to_integer and it starts things off by calling the lambda ZERO and sending in INCR:

```
ZERO[INCR]
=> #<Proc:0x007ff86a0decf0@(irb):103 (lambda)>
```

As you can see this returns another lambda(the one defined in ZERO where p is set to INCR). We can now start the ball rolling by calling this lambda and sending in 0:

```
ZERO[INCR][0]
=> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

A proc literal has the syntax "-> parameters { body }". An concrete example of a proc literal to increment a number is "-> n { n + 1 }". For readability, a proc literal can be assigned to a variable, e.g. "INCREMENT = -> n { n + 1 }".

A proc literal can be called by using square brackets "-> parameters { body }[arguments]". Using the previous example, here's how to increment 9 to give you 10 "-> n { n + 1 }[9]". The passed in argument "9" is represented by the parameter "n" in the body, and 1 is added to "n" to give the result. Again, for readability, "INCREMENT[9]" can be used to give the same result.

Now let's look at "ZERO = -> p { -> x { x } }". When "ZERO[INCREMENT][0]" is executed, the "ZERO[INCREMENT]" part is executed first. The result is "-> x { x }" and, by substitution, the original statement becomes "-> x { x }[0]". When that is executed, it returns a 0.

Now let's look at "ONE  = -> p { -> x { p[x] } }". When "ONE[INCREMENT][0]" is executed, the "ONE[INCREMENT]" part is executed first. The result is "-> x { p[x] }" where p is "INCREMENT". By substitution, the original statement becomes "-> x { INCREMENT[x] }[0]". When that is executed, basically INCREMENT is called with 0, i.e. "INCREMENT[0]", and the result is 1.

Finally, let's look at:
def to_integer(proc)
  proc[-> n { n + 1 }][0]
end

"to_integer(ZERO)" executes "ZERO[-> n { n + 1 }][0]". Note that "-> n { n + 1}" is the same as INCREMENT, so that execution is the same as ZERO[INCREMENT][0]. And as stated above, that produces 0.

"to_integer(ONE)" executes "ONE[-> n { n + 1 }][0]". Note that "-> n { n + 1}" is the same as INCREMENT, so that execution is the same as ONE[INCREMENT][0]. And as stated above, that produces 1.

The same process can be applied to TWO, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well the base idea here actually came from constructing natural numbers as in Peano Axioms (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms)

Therefore zero is 0, one is S(0), two is S(S(0)), three is S(S(S(0))) etc (where S is some function).

Secondly this method may be rewritten, substituting `[]` for `call`:

```
def to_integer(proc)
  proc.call(Proc.new { |n| n + 1 }).call(0)
end
```

And we can see now clearly it does reverse computation - when we try to count how many is one (which actually is S(0), or in our notation `-> p { -> x { p[x] } }` which is equivalent to `Proc.new { |p| Proc.new { |x| p.call(x) } }`, it stores information about that it needs to S(x), where is something we don't know (argument of our proc)

And now is the tricky part. Here Ruby calls our definition of one (it's a Proc, so it can be called!) passing as argument another Proc - this one is equivalent to S function (n + 1). So before final `.call(0)` we have sequence of Procs - calling deeper one with argument increased by 1 (because of our integer) - S(x). And by final call(0) we set base of our natural numbers S(0).

Maybe it will be helpful to consider some examples:

What number we will get when we substitute `to_integer` with:

```
def to_integer(proc)
  proc[-> n { n + 1 }][0]
end
```

(it may be interesting that this numbers are as good natural numbers as standard one).

What will happen if we change the base in call, from 0 to 1?